# TVS Diode Array with EMI Filters on ADC Input

Tags: adc, emc, tvs

Is there any problem with using this [SP6002](http://www.littelfuse.com/data/en/Data_Sheets/Littelfuse_TVS_Diode_Array_SPA_SP6002.pdf) TVS Diode Array/EMI filter to protect ADC inputs on a micro-controller? The ADCs will only measure DC voltages. I am a little worried that the filters will affect the ADC readings as I have never put EMI filters on an ADC input before.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the ADC and what input voltage range it needs. The SP6002 has a stand-off voltage of 6 V and, at  5V, it promises to only conduct no more than 1 uA. However, it only conducts 1mA at possibly 8.5 V so is it going to protect an ADC running from a 5 V supply? I don't think so - a lot of CPU in-built ADCs will not want voltages going more than half a volt beyond the supply rail so I think it won't suit these devices.

The series resistance won't be a problem and I doubt that the shunt capacitance is going to affect signals for this type of ADC.